# Proxy servlet and iframe to run site from another domain

Tags: java, servlets

For quite a long time I use proxy servlet, and from my experience in order for javascript to properly work, the proxy servlet has to be configured to run in the ROOT context. However, a site http://www.filestube.com/ from what I investigated, its running a site from another domain on a iframe.

I am wondering what kind of approach is this?

Comment: What site is running from another domain? I only see facebook iframe. An iframe is designed to be used with any url address. In fact, the whole html is designed so that you can put your javascript, css, images on another domain anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see on the target page it loads javascript from some 'local' domains (*.filestube.com) who then in turn load javascript from another domain (e.G. google or facebook in this case).

Also there is an IFrame on the site, but IFrames may come from everywhere anyway.

So the kind of approach is: Normal, don't think about user privacy and just load everything you think you might need from everywhere.

Comment: Where you say load everything from everywhere, how is that?

Comment: Is it not subject to browser, cross-domain policy, I mean I tried loading url in iframe but it gets cross domain policy problem.

Comment: ah, now I see what you mean. I will investigate it further (cause its interesting) meanwhile have a look at: http://www.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/